# Create a `map` using `unique_ptr`

Tags: c++, dictionary, unique-ptr

I originally had a problem creating a `map` of classes, with some help
I realized I actually need a `map<string, unique_ptr<myclass>>`.

To be more precise:

- I have a bunch of specialized classes with a common ancestor.
- specialized classes are actually specialized from the same template.
- I have a `std::map<std::string, unique_ptr<ancestor>>` taking ownership
  of my instances (I hope).
- I need ownership because the function creating the instances is in a
  completely different section of code than the place using them.
- If useful: I create the `map` at initialization time and then I only
  reference it at runtime; for all practical purposes after initializing
  it (a complex affair, involving reading config files) it could become
  `const`.

A minimal example of what I need to achieve is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

class generic {
    std::string _name;

public:
    generic(std::string name) : _name(name) {}
    virtual ~generic() = default;

    virtual std::string name() { return _name; }
    virtual std::string value() { return "no value in generic"; }
};

template <class T> class special : public generic {
    T _value;
public:
    special(std::string name, T value) : generic(name), _value(value) {}
    virtual ~special() = default;

    std::string value() override { return std::to_string(_value); }
};

template <typename T> void add_item(std::map <std::string, std::unique_ptr<generic>> &m, const std::string &n, const T &v) {
    m[n] = std::make_unique<special<T>>(typeid(v).name(), v);
}

int
main() {
    std::map <std::string, std::unique_ptr<generic>> instances;

    add_item<int>(instances, "int", 1);
    add_item<bool>(instances, "bool", true);
    add_item<float>(instances, "float", 3.1415);

    for (auto i : instances) {
        std::cout << i.first << " -- " << i.second.get()->name() << " -- " << i.second.get()->value() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately I seem to be missing something because compilation bombs with "error: use of deleted function".

Can someone be so kind to help me sort this out?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<T>` doesn't provide a copy constructor.

Comment: Last time I checked, `unique_ptr<T>` cannot be used as a map value, because the map must copy values around in order to rebalance the tree, and `unique_ptr<T>` isn't copyable. I would have thought the "new" (I haven't used C++ in a very long time) move semantics stuff could have addressed that, though.

Comment: *"compilation bombs with 'error: use of deleted function'."* -- the full error message should mention *which* deleted function is being used (and also where in your code you are using it).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't think a `std::map` requires the value to be neither copyable nor moveable. Rebalancing the tree should be possible without copying/moving the values around.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Of course you can. See https://godbolt.org/z/q3jW891xn.

Comment: I probably just mis-remember, then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this loop you try to copy `unique_ptr`s, but the `unique_ptr` copy constructor is deleted.

```
for (auto i : instances) {
```

You need to take them by reference instead:

```
for (auto& i : instances) {
```